# Python Speaker Recognition

Tags: python, voice-recognition, speech

I have an audio file, a recorded telephone conversation of 2 people, that I need to separate the voices of 2 speakers automatically. I am new to speech recognition and I looked at wave module of python but failed to find any fruitful information.

Please help how to start. Also please suggest me free python libraries which will help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 16):

The task of separation of the speakers is not a speech recognition task, it's a speaker recognition task. In the speech comminity this task is also known as speaker diarization. There are several packages for speaker diarization and speaker recognition available for Python:

[SIDEKIT from LIUM](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIDEKIT)

[Bob toolkit from Idiap](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.bio.spear/stable/index.html#bob-bio-spear)

[Speaker diarization from ISCI](https://github.com/hcook/gmm)

In case you are not restricted to Python, there are others:

[LIUM speaker diarization](http://lium3.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/welcome)

[Speaker recognition setup in Kaldi](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/sre10/v2). Includes state of the art DNN-based i-vectors called x-vectors.

Comment: The link for Bob toolkit is actually dead, follow this one : https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.bio.spear/stable/index.html#bob-bio-spear

Comment: Updated, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Start with numpy, and I would look at spectrpgraphs (basically a rolling FFT) as a good method for distinguish different voices in an audio recording.

Here's the spectrogram function in [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/):

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram

I would recommend [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) if you're just getting started on a Windows platform.

Answer (score 2):

Check out sciKits Talkbox: http://projects.scipy.org/scikits/wiki/Talkbox

Unfortunutly tutorials are very restricted: http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/talkbox/talkbox_doc/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CMU Sphinx Python library. It's developed in Java so I think that the Python libs are just wrappers for that. The project has a lot of ongoing research behind it.

Official wiki: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

Quick-start  tutorial for linux here: http://probing.wikidot.com/speech-recognition-using-sphinx3-and-python