# Speaker Recognition System using Python

Tags: python, voice-recognition, mfcc, gmm

I'm trying to make a **Speaker** recognition (not speech but speaker) system using Python. I've extracted `mfcc` features of both train audio file and test audio file and have made a `gmm` model for each. I'm not sure how to compare the models to compute a score of similarity based on which I can program the system to validate the test audio. I'm struggling for 4 days to get this done. Would be glad if someone can help.

Comment: Please provide more details and show your efforts (If any).

Comment: im taking 3 audio files to model a training set(.gmm) and then taking one more audio clip(test clip) to compare it with the training model to compute the similarity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Speaker Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309219/python-speaker-recognition)

Answer (score -1):

From what I can understand from the question, you are describing an aspect of the [cocktail party problem](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2692487/)
I have found [a whitepaper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224247801_Speech_separation_by_simulating_the_cocktail_party_effect_with_a_neural_network_controlled_Wiener_filter0) with a solution to your problem using a modified iterative Wiener filter and a multi-layer perceptron neural network that can separate speakers into separate channels.

Intrestingly the cocktail party problem can be solved in one line in ocatve: `[W,s,v]=svd((repmat(sum(x.*x,1),size(x,1),1).*x)*x');`

you can read more about it on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414667/cocktail-party-algorithm-svd-implementation-in-one-line-of-code/20432031)